# Problems with Destroy and Delete functions Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, destroy

I decided to change the destroy function on my app to just switch a Status field to false (The index and show actions only show the results with status: true).

Well, I've changed this, and it worked at first, but now it's just "rolling back" before it complete the commit...

The controller destroy :

```
def destroy
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@contact = @customer.contacts
@adress = @customer.adresses

if @customer.delete(current_user)
  @contact.each do |f|
    f.delete(current_user)
  end
  @adress.each do |g|
    @telephone = g.telephones
    @telephone.each do |t|
      t.delete(current_user)
    end
    g.delete(current_user)
  end
  flash[:success] = "Cliente excluído"
else
  flash[:danger] = "Erro! O cliente não foi excluído."
end
redirect_to customers_path
end
```

The model delete :

```
def delete(user_id)
update_attributes(status: false, changed_by: user_id, deleted_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
end
```

Besides that I restricted the :destroy method only to Admin (Is that the right method? Why is it not delete?)

Thanks!

Comment: You can use paranoia gem for this functionality

Comment: Change `update_attributes(...)` to `update_attributes!(...)` and try again. `update_attributes!` would raise an exception when the update fails. That exception tells you why the update failed (usually failing validation).

Comment: No its not right its totally BAD! Whats your database association ?

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse but overwriting the delete functionality feels like a code smell.  If you want soft deletes I would look at the paranoid gem or at least use a method more appropriately named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue with the rolling back is likely related to a validation failure. You can find out what this is by changing `update_attributes` into `update_attributes!`This will throw an error when the validation fails and you can see what went wrong.

Apart from that there are a few ways you can improve your code

First off, rather than manually deleting a customer's contacts and address you can add dependent: :destroy to the relation.

This works like so:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :adresses, dependent: :destroy
end

class Adress < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :telephones, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When you call `.destroy` on a record it will call `.destroy` on any relations that have dependent: :destroy on them. `.delete` will not do this pass through, that is the major difference between them.

By adding that to the above relations like so you can change your controller to this:

```
def destroy
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  if @customer.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Cliente excluído"
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Erro! O cliente não foi excluído."
  end
  redirect_to customers_path
end
```

This will destroy the customer, it's adresses, and the addresses' telephones.

#### The non-permanent delete

To do a soft-delete like you want you should use the [Paranoia](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) gem.
It lets you assign a class with `acts_as_paranoid` so when you call `.delete` or `.destroy` it isn't really removed, it is just hidden and can be recovered later.

It is well integrated with Activerecord so you won't need to do things like `Customer.where(status: true)` to get your non-deleted records, it just won't include deleted records by default. Although you can request them if you need.

The gem's Github page does a really good job of explaining how to use it.

By default it won't save the user that performed the deletion, just the time it was performed at. If you want to do that you should create a wrapper that calls delete after assigning the user that performed the deletion.

Something like this should work:

```
def destroy_by(user)
  update_attributes!(changed_by: user)
  destroy
end
```

Then you can change `@customer.destroy` in your controller to `@customer.destroy_by(current_user)`

There is no need to override or restrict delete or destroy.

Comment: Okay! That way really looks more trustworthy and secure to do the soft delete. Thanks!!